# mysql_query (UPDATE ...) SEEMS to return true before database values are actually updated

Tags: mysql, soap, sql-update, synchronous

Two consecutive SOAP messages are sent to a LAMP stack from an iOS App where the first is a mysql_query (UPDATE ...) and the second is a mysql_query (SELECT ...).  The second query returns old information for one of the fields even though the first query returns success for updating that field in the database.  Is mysql_query returning true for UPDATE even though the fields in the database are not updated yet?  Or am I somehow getting cached information with the second query? A refresh of the second query a few seconds later shows the updated information.

Comment: Please provide query procedures.

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue. It was the iOS App. The second SOAP message was being sent asynchronously from the first.